# PostgreSQL terrible performance with query if tables not in Public schema

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

So I have a query which aims to join multiple tables on a common field using LEFT JOIN. When I have these tables in the Public schema, the execution of the query with LIMIT 1 takes less than a second. When I move the tables to a different Schema which is where I want them, and update the query to reference the new schema, the same query takes over 30 seconds. A shortened version of my query is below. What am I missing?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (studies.nct_id) studies.nct_id,
 array_to_string(ARRAY( SELECT sponsors_1.name
       FROM public.sponsors sponsors_1
      WHERE ((studies.nct_id)::text = (sponsors_1.nct_id)::text)), ' | '::text) AS sponsor,
 studies.phase,
 studies.overall_status,
 array_to_string(ARRAY( SELECT conditions_1.name
       FROM public.conditions conditions_1
      WHERE ((studies.nct_id)::text = (conditions_1.nct_id)::text)), ' | '::text) AS condition,
 studies.brief_title,
 studies.official_title,
 ((((((('Allocation: '::text || (COALESCE(designs.allocation, ''::character varying))::text) || ' | Intervention Model: '::text) || (COALESCE(designs.intervention_model, ''::character varying))::text) || ' | Masking: '::text) || (COALESCE(designs.masking))::text) || ' | Primary Purpose: '::text) || (COALESCE(designs.primary_purpose, ''::character varying))::text) AS  study_design,
 studies.study_type,
array_to_string(ARRAY( SELECT interventions_1.name
       FROM public.interventions interventions_1
      WHERE ((studies.nct_id)::text = (interventions_1.nct_id)::text)), ' | '::text) AS intervention,
array_to_string(ARRAY( SELECT interventions_1.description
       FROM public.interventions interventions_1
      WHERE ((studies.nct_id)::text = (interventions_1.nct_id)::text)), ' | '::text) AS intervention_description,
studies.enrollment,
studies.number_of_arms,
studies.number_of_groups,
array_to_string(ARRAY( SELECT design_outcomes_1.measure
       FROM public.design_outcomes design_outcomes_1
      WHERE (((studies.nct_id)::text = (design_outcomes_1.nct_id)::text) AND ((design_outcomes_1.outcome_type)::text = 'primary'::text))), ' | '::text) AS primary_outcome_measures,
array_to_string(ARRAY( SELECT design_outcomes_1.measure
       FROM public.design_outcomes design_outcomes_1
      WHERE (((studies.nct_id)::text = (design_outcomes_1.nct_id)::text) AND ((design_outcomes_1.outcome_type)::text = 'secondary'::text))), ' | '::text) AS secondary_outcome_measures,
studies.first_received_date,
studies.last_changed_date,
studies.first_received_results_date,
studies.study_first_submitted_date,
studies.last_update_submitted_date,
studies.study_first_posted_date,
studies.last_update_posted_date,
studies.start_date,
studies.verification_date,
studies.completion_date,
studies.primary_completion_date,
studies.target_duration
FROM (((((public.studies
 LEFT JOIN public.conditions ON (((studies.nct_id)::text = (conditions.nct_id)::text)))
 LEFT JOIN public.sponsors ON (((studies.nct_id)::text = (sponsors.nct_id)::text)))
 LEFT JOIN public.interventions ON (((studies.nct_id)::text = (interventions.nct_id)::text)))
 LEFT JOIN public.designs ON (((studies.nct_id)::text = (designs.nct_id)::text)))
 LEFT JOIN public.design_outcomes ON (((studies.nct_id)::text = (design_outcomes.nct_id)::text)))
```

Once I move the tables to my new schema, I simply replace the references of public to the new schema name, but then the performance is really bad. Why could this be?

Edit: Execution plan below:

```
"Limit  (cost=1197867.37..34018752836.17 rows=1 width=549) (actual time=42498.945..42498.946 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=5999 read=95047, temp read=79529 written=134247"
"  ->  Unique  (cost=1197867.37..9354725564952744.00 rows=274997 width=549) (actual time=42498.943..42498.943 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=5999 read=95047, temp read=79529 written=134247"
"        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1197867.37..9354713282264832.00 rows=4913075164798 width=549) (actual time=42498.941..42498.941 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              Merge Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (design_outcomes.nct_id)::text)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=5999 read=95047, temp read=79529 written=134247"
"              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1197866.81..1644474160.20 rows=100675927415 width=380) (actual time=42463.489..42463.489 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    Merge Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (interventions.nct_id)::text)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=5951 read=95031, temp read=79529 written=134247"
"                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1197866.38..111582984.04 rows=5777450620 width=380) (actual time=42463.320..42463.320 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                          Merge Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (conditions.nct_id)::text)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=5947 read=95031, temp read=79529 written=134247"
"                          ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1197865.94..16300918.47 rows=354541589 width=380) (actual time=42463.129..42463.129 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                Merge Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (sponsors.nct_id)::text)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=5943 read=95031, temp read=79529 written=134247"
"                                ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1197865.51..4237696.75 rows=24884088 width=380) (actual time=42462.744..42462.744 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                      Workers Planned: 2"
"                                      Workers Launched: 2"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=5939 read=95031, temp read=79529 written=134247"
"                                      ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1196865.49..1364455.53 rows=10368370 width=380) (actual time=42015.478..42015.783 rows=208 loops=3)"
"                                            Merge Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (designs.nct_id)::text)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=16253 read=284266, temp read=234103 written=397065"
"                                            ->  Sort  (cost=609424.37..612009.01 rows=1033853 width=325) (actual time=14020.417..14020.454 rows=21 loops=3)"
"                                                  Sort Key: studies.nct_id"
"                                                  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 267024kB"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=682 read=184166, temp read=143141 written=241594"
"                                                  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on studies  (cost=0.00..195176.53 rows=1033853 width=325) (actual time=1.795..4267.210 rows=827082 loops=3)"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=672 read=184166"
"                                            ->  Materialize  (cost=587441.12..601231.54 rows=2758084 width=67) (actual time=27995.046..27995.177 rows=208 loops=3)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=15571 read=100100, temp read=90962 written=155471"
"                                                  ->  Sort  (cost=587441.12..594336.33 rows=2758084 width=67) (actual time=27995.032..27995.139 rows=75 loops=3)"
"                                                        Sort Key: designs.nct_id"
"                                                        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 173208kB"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=15571 read=100100, temp read=90962 written=155471"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on designs  (cost=0.00..66137.84 rows=2758084 width=67) (actual time=0.842..1177.338 rows=2756910 loops=3)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=15571 read=100100"
"                                ->  Materialize  (cost=0.43..6692683.76 rows=3918443 width=12) (actual time=0.378..0.378 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=4"
"                                      ->  Index Only Scan using index_sponsors_on_nct_id on sponsors  (cost=0.43..6682887.65 rows=3918443 width=12) (actual time=0.322..0.322 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                            Heap Fetches: 1"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=4"
"                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.43..7745155.44 rows=4481997 width=12) (actual time=0.187..0.187 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=4"
"                                ->  Index Only Scan using index_conditions_on_nct_id on conditions  (cost=0.43..7733950.45 rows=4481997 width=12) (actual time=0.184..0.184 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                      Heap Fetches: 1"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=4"
"                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.43..8320619.63 rows=4792460 width=12) (actual time=0.165..0.165 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=4"
"                          ->  Index Only Scan using index_interventions_on_nct_id on interventions  (cost=0.43..8308638.48 rows=4792460 width=12) (actual time=0.160..0.160 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                Heap Fetches: 1"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=4"
"              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.56..24467676.48 rows=13422054 width=12) (actual time=0.115..0.115 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=5"
"                    ->  Index Only Scan using index_design_outcomes_on_nct_id on design_outcomes  (cost=0.56..24434121.35 rows=13422054 width=12) (actual time=0.111..0.111 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                          Heap Fetches: 1"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=5"
"              SubPlan 1"
"                ->  Index Scan using index_sponsors_on_nct_id on sponsors sponsors_1  (cost=0.43..92.02 rows=22 width=30) (actual time=0.042..12.632 rows=9 loops=1)"
"                      Index Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (nct_id)::text)"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=5 read=7"
"              SubPlan 2"
"                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on conditions conditions_1  (cost=4.67..122.82 rows=30 width=21) (actual time=0.038..0.059 rows=10 loops=1)"
"                      Recheck Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (nct_id)::text)"
"                      Heap Blocks: exact=10"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=13"
"                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_conditions_on_nct_id  (cost=0.00..4.66 rows=30 width=0) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=10 loops=1)"
"                            Index Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (nct_id)::text)"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=3"
"              SubPlan 3"
"                ->  Index Scan using index_interventions_on_nct_id on interventions interventions_1  (cost=0.43..132.42 rows=32 width=21) (actual time=0.017..22.442 rows=10 loops=1)"
"                      Index Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (nct_id)::text)"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=4 read=9"
"              SubPlan 4"
"                ->  Index Scan using index_interventions_on_nct_id on interventions interventions_1_1  (cost=0.43..132.42 rows=32 width=141) (actual time=0.039..0.047 rows=10 loops=1)"
"                      Index Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (nct_id)::text)"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=13"
"              SubPlan 5"
"                ->  Index Scan using index_design_outcomes_on_nct_id on design_outcomes design_outcomes_1  (cost=0.56..712.16 rows=55 width=61) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                      Index Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (nct_id)::text)"
"                      Filter: ((outcome_type)::text = 'primary'::text)"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=4"
"              SubPlan 6"
"                ->  Index Scan using index_design_outcomes_on_nct_id on design_outcomes design_outcomes_1_1  (cost=0.56..712.16 rows=115 width=61) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                      Index Cond: ((studies.nct_id)::text = (nct_id)::text)"
"                      Filter: ((outcome_type)::text = 'secondary'::text)"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=4"
"Planning time: 7.978 ms"
"Execution time: 42859.072 ms"
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) of the slow version generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: A shot in the dark: after moving the tables to a different schema, did you `analyze` them to update statistics?

Comment: Hi, added the execution plan of the slow query. Btw I don't actually move the tables, I restore them from a backup file. So I restored the tables to public, and to ctgov, but queries to ctgov are very bad.

Comment: Ok I have just noticed something. The queries between the two schemas return slightly different results! As you can see in my query, I use an array_to_string (ARRAY.. in order to get rows from different tables and use those row values as the column value separated by '|' character. In the quick query it returns the distinct row values, however in the slow query it returns many more rows. I don't understand why it would do this, the query is the same.

Comment: If you _restored_ the tables, they definitely do not have up-to-date statistics. You have to analyze all of the restored tables.

Comment: I just performed an ANALYZE on each table involved in the query, it hasn't changed the query time.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out my issue, and I suspected it was something dumb from my side. Apparently my restore command was not clearing the database before restoring, so it kept on adding to it and as a result was 10 times larger than it should have been. So the above discussion is moot.